# Startup screen for Android app using jQuery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile-application

I’m building an Android app using jQuery mobile and PhoneGap. How can I show an image as a startup screen for the app, just for a few seconds, before the login screen appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this while the application starts-up then you have to look for help regarding android native applications and use the solution in your phonegap project so that the phonegap application has the splashscreen. Then after you build it - you should have a splashscreen.

If all you want is a splash screen for the time after the phonegap application starts and before the phonegap api is ready (it fires the event) then you have to put the splashscreen in HTML and hide it in your event handler. [but I bet it's not what you wanted]

Answer (score 4):

This might also be useful: If you scroll down to where it says "Splash Screens" (Kind of far down into the page) you'll see how to set up a splash screen for your app with config.xml in PhoneGap:

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml